# How to make a model reset into a position that I set

Tags: modeling, animation, bones

I want to make running and idle animations for my model but each time I reset the position to start the other animation it puts it back into  a t pose so I have to reposition the fists each time which takes so long! how do I make it so that I reset it into a position that I want such as the one below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use **Pose Library** ...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! It worked immediately

Comment: Great ... If the answer is correct for you, consider to click on check-mark under vote arrows to sign this answer as "solved" (that is only your privilege), so others can easily see it from a list of questions (don't worry, you can uncheck it any time in a future). Thank you keep this site organised :)